# changing Vmargs in eclipse

Tags: java, memory, ram, vmargs

I have a rediculous problem in eclipse memory allocation.
I have a code , when I run it without changing the Vmargs it starts from 250mg and ends in 904mg,without any error and when I change the Vmargs to -Xmx2g it starts from 750mg and ends in 1.2G.
does the value of VMargs affect the memory usage of the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good for me, maybe all your Eclipse need is 1.2G

If your Java is 32 bit only then maybe you can't get more RAM. Java need **heap memory** and **non heap memory**. Java 32 bit has limit to 4g or less (this depend on system and hardware)

More about this:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm

Comment: it differs when I change the vmargs. I don't know does it really need more than 1g or no?

Comment: Java likes memory and have very complicated algorithm for allocating memory. If it works without 1g then dont need 1g.